# @Service/@Controller annotations creates a new bean without using @Bean annotation

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I have a class which I have annotated with @Service @Scope

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ProductDataModel {
@Value("${message}")
private String message;
```

The above code seems to be creating a bean for ProductDataModel, without using the @Bean annotation.

I am using `@Autowired ProductDataModel productDataModel` in my code, and the dependency productDataModel is not null, when used with above piece of Code.

How come the above code is creating bean ??

Ideally, I would have expected bean to created only when I use the below code

```
//I am not using this piece of code in my program., for reference only

@Configuration
public class OSCConfig {

@Bean
 @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
ProductDataModel productDataModel(){
return new ProductDataModel();
}
```

Can someone explain the difference between 2 pieces of code and when to use which one.

Comment: It is component-scanned. You don't need to specify a `@Bean` for each and every class/bean you want to use. If you put `@Component` or one of the specialized versions like `@Service` on a class it will be detected automatically when using component-scanning.

Comment: If that's the case, then @Bean should be used only when we are using declaring beans with constructor or for specifying the lifecycle callback methods like init, cleanup etc.

Comment: No not really, you can do all those things without an `@Bean` ...

Comment: Really, good to know that. Then does that mean @Bean is redundant and need to be only used say if we don't have that class with us and referring to a third party jar class. Where we cant add @Service/@Controller annotations

Comment: You could or if you want to do some custom logic (as it is Java you can do a lot of things inside a `@Bean` annotated method).

Answer (score 2):

As @M. Deinum pointed out that we don't need to specify @Bean for each class when we declare @Service or @Controller annotation they are picked up by Spring Container if component-scanning is enabled for that package.

So good use case for using @Bean could be that

- If the Class is in third party jar and you can not add @Service/@Controller annotations
- If you want to add some custom logic inside the @Bean annotate methods

Answer (score 0):

The @Service annotation is picked up by Spring when scanning for objects to create (as part of a package scan).  It is an specialisation of the spring @Component annotation, but doesn't really add much other than providing an indication to users about its intended purpose. The @Controlller annotation is similar, but the bean created has specific characteristics.

The @Bean annotation as you have used it is also used when creating objects, and in this context it is on a method in a Configuration class, therefore the bean created is of the type returned by the method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's my Question @Service +@Scope creates a new bean instance without using@Bean.. I have edited my question for better understanding.